# Is there an open source .NET Core Library or Software to enqueue HTTP requests

Tags: web-server, synchronization

I have a cluster of web servers behind a web balancer with an API that was designed to received sporadic requests for repeat customers.

So for example, today I receive a first request for customer A and in a week I will receive another request for the same customer. Each request can take maybe a minute to be processed and they need to be processed in order.

The normal flow would be:

1st Request > 1st Request Processing > 1st Response > ... > 2st Request > 2st Request Processing > 2st Response

But lately one of the API clients is sending multiple requests at the same time, since the first request is not completely processed when the second request arrives, this sometimes causes a race condition and the requests are not being processed as expected.

The API client cannot wait for the first successful response before sending the second request, and they want me to support this use case so I implement basic queuing in the API so if I receive multiple requests from the same customer, the second request is not processed until the first request is completely processed. We asked the web balancer team that requests from the same customer should be sent to the same web server for this queuing to work as expected and it was working pretty well until recently.

Suddenly the web balancer is not able to send multiple requests from the same customer to the same web server, so the simultaneous requests are reaching different web servers and since there are not a "synchronized queueing" between servers we are back to the original issue.

They want me to solve this scenario from my side, so I was wondering if there exists an open source .NET Core library or software that can solve this kind of enqueuing needs.